# OPTIONS request failed on '/svn' - Unable to create a branch from the truck of my SVN Repository

Tags: svn, version-control, phpstorm, visualsvn, phpstorm-2017.2

I am using PhpStorm and a Visual SVN repository. I have been able to create branches from trunk projects before, but recently when I try to create a branch on an up-to-date project, I recieve this error:

**Error:svn: E175002: Processing OPTIONS request response failed: Premature end of file. (/svn) 
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn'**

Other members on my team are able to create branches from the same project I am trying to create a branch from without problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like some issue of the SVNKit. Try enabling integration via a command-line client in **Settings - Version control - Subversion - General**.

The issue seems to be related to invalid response received from the server. Could be caused by proxy if you use one.

Comment: Would I need to download a command-line client to be able to use this option? We would like to be able to do all of our SVN work with the PhpStorm svn bundle

Comment: Yes, to integrate via command-line client you need to download one.

Comment: Will I be able to fix this problem without using a command-line client?

Comment: Switching the integration component to the command-line client from SVNKit java library is not the same as using the client from command prompt. Just try it.

Comment: I have done this with TortoiseSVN. Now, I am recieving an error saying working copy for file can not be found even though I have my working copy open.

Comment: I also checked out the trunk of a project using the Tortoise SVN client through PhpStorm, then tried to create a branch and received the same error that I was originally seeing.

Comment: enable debug logs by adding `#org.jetbrains.idea.svn` to Help - Debug Log settings... and check the logs for an exact command that is failing. Then you could test it via command-line client to see what exactly is wrong